# How to handle FIFO queue for producer-consumer pattern

Tags: c, semaphore, producer-consumer, fifo

I've a FIFO queue, producers and consumers which I try in different combinations which works except just this arrangement. I'm supposed to be able to run this with 3 Producers, 2 Consumers, 10 slots for the FIFO, and no semaphores to begin with, and then also make it with semaphores active.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "oslab_lowlevel_h.h"

int NextPrime( int );

#define FIFO_SIZE 10

/* Declare a structure to hold a producer's starting value,
 * and an integer for the Producer-number (Producer 1, 2 or 3). */
struct Prod {
    int startvalue;
    int id;
};

unsigned int stack1[0x400]; /* Stack for thread 1 */
unsigned int stack2[0x400]; /* Stack for thread 2 */
unsigned int stack3[0x400]; /* Stack for thread 3 */
unsigned int stack4[0x400]; /* Stack for thread 4 */
unsigned int stack5[0x400]; /* Stack for thread 5 */

/* Declare variables for the First-In-First-Out Queue */
int  Fifo[FIFO_SIZE];        /* Array holding FIFO queue data. */
int  rdaddr;                /* Next unread entry when reading from queue. */
int  wraddr;                /* Next free entry when writing into queue. */

/* Declaration of semaphore variables.
 */
int  rdmutex = 1;
int  wrmutex = 1;
int  nrempty = FIFO_SIZE;
int  nrfull = 0;

/*
 * fatal_error
 * 
 * Print a message, then stop execution.
 * This function never returns; after printing
 * the message, it enters an infinite loop.
 */
void fatal_error( char * msg)
{
  printf( "\nFatal error: %s\n", msg );
  while( 1 );
}

/*
 * Sleep
 * 
 * Delay execution by keeping the CPU busy for a while,
 * counting down to zero.
 */
void Sleep (int n)
{
    while (n--);
}

/*
 * Signal
 * 
 * Semaphore operation: add to semaphore,
 * possibly allowing other threads to continue.
 */
void Signal( int *sem )
{
  /* We must disable interrupts, since the operation
   * *sem = *sem + 1
   * will require several machine instructions on Nios2.
   * If we have a timer-interrupt and a thread-switch
   * somewhere in the middle of those machine instructions,
   * the semaphore will be updated twice, or not at all, or
   * in some other erroneous way.
   */
  oslab_begin_critical_region();
  *sem = *sem + 1;
  oslab_end_critical_region();
}

/*
 * Wait
 * 
 * Sempahore operation: check semaphore, and
 * wait if the semaphore value is zero or less.
 */
void Wait( int *sem )
{
  /* Disable interrupts. */
  oslab_begin_critical_region();
  while ( *sem <= 0 )
    {
      /* If we should wait, enable interrupts again. */
      oslab_end_critical_region();

        //oslab_yield(); /* Perhaps we should yield here? */

      /* Disable interrupts again before next iteration in loop. */
      oslab_begin_critical_region();
    }
    /* We have waited long enough - the semaphore-value is now
     * greater than zero. Decrease it. */
    *sem = *sem - 1;
    /* Enable interrupts again. */
    oslab_end_critical_region();
}

/*
 * PutFifo
 * 
 * Insert an integer into the FIFO queue.
 */
void PutFifo( int tal )
{
    //Wait (&nrempty);      /* Wait for nrempty? */
    //Wait (&wrmutex);      /* Wait for wrmutex? */

  Fifo[wraddr] = tal;       /* Write to FIFO array. */
    //  printf("\nPutFifo:  %d ", tal); /* Optional debug output */
     // printf("\nwraddr = %d ", wraddr); /* Optional debug output. */
  wraddr = wraddr + 1;      /* Increase index into FIFO array,
                               to point to the next free position. */
  /* Wrap around the index, if it has reached the end of the array. */
  if (wraddr == FIFO_SIZE ) wraddr = 0;

    //Signal (&wrmutex);    /* Signal wrmutex? */
    //Signal (&nrfull);     /* Signal nrfull? */
}

/*
 * GetFifo
 * 
 * Extract the next integer from the FIFO queue.
 */
int GetFifo( void )
{
  int retval;               /* Declare temporary for return value. */

    //Wait (&nrfull);       /* Wait for nrfull? */
    //Wait (&rdmutex);      /* Wait for rdmutex? */

  retval = Fifo[rdaddr];    /* Get value from FIFO array. */
  //    printf("\nGetFifo:  %d ", retval); /* Optional debug output */
  //    printf("\nrdaddr = %d ", rdaddr); /* Optional debug output */
  rdaddr = rdaddr + 1;      /* Increase index into FIFO array,
                               to point to the next free position. */
  /* Wrap around the index, if it has reached the end of the array. */
  if (rdaddr == FIFO_SIZE ) rdaddr = 0;

    //Signal (&rdmutex);    /* Signal rdmutex? */
    //Signal (&nrempty);    /* Signal nrempty? */

  return (retval);          /* Return value fetched from FIFO. */
}

/*
 * NextPrime
 * 
 * Return the first prime number larger than the integer
 * given as a parameter. The integer must be positive.
 * 
 * *** NextPrime is outside the focus of this assignment. ***
 * The definition of NextPrime can be found at the end of this file.
 * The short declaration here is required by the compiler.
 */
int NextPrime( int );

void Producer( struct Prod * prodstruct )
{
  int next;                 /* Will hold the prime we just produced. */
  int prodid;               /* Tells whether we are producer 1, 2 or 3. */
  next = prodstruct -> startvalue; /* Get starting value from parameter. */
  prodid = prodstruct -> id;/* Get producer number from parameter. */
  while( 1 )                /* Loop forever. */
  {
    next = NextPrime (next);/* Produce a new prime. */
    printf("\nNext Prime from producer %d is %d",prodid,next); /* Informational output. */
    PutFifo(next);          /* Write prime into FIFO. */
  //  oslab_yield();        /* Perhaps we should yield here? */
  }
}

void Consumer( int * tal )
{
  int next;                 /* Will hold the prime we are to consume. */
  int consid = *tal;        /* Tells whether we are consumer 1 or 2. */
  while( 1 )                /* Loop forever. */
  {
    next = GetFifo();       /* Get a newly produced prime from the FIFO. */
    printf("\nConsumer %d gets Prime %d ",consid, next); /* Informational output. */
    Sleep(2000);            /* Symbolic work. */
    //oslab_yield();        /* Perhaps we should yield here? */
  }
}

int main( void )
{
  int new_thread_id; /* Thread ID variable. */
  struct Prod prod1, prod2, prod3;  /* Producer starting-values. */
  int cons1, cons2;                 /* Consumer starting-values. */

  rdaddr = 0;               /* FIFO initialization. */
  wraddr = 0;               /* FIFO initialization. */
  printf("\nSystem starting...");

  prod1.startvalue = 2000;
  prod1.id = 1;

  prod2.startvalue = 5000;
  prod2.id = 2;

  prod3.startvalue = 8000;
  prod3.id = 3;

  cons1 = 1;
  cons2 = 2;

  new_thread_id = oslab_create_thread((void *)Producer, &prod1, &(stack1[0x3ff]));
  if( new_thread_id < 0 ) fatal_error( "cannot start Producer 1" );
  printf("\nProducer %d is created with thread-ID %d", prod1.id, new_thread_id);

  new_thread_id = oslab_create_thread((void *)Producer, &prod2, &(stack2[0x3ff]));
  if( new_thread_id < 0 ) fatal_error( "cannot start Producer 2" );
  printf("\nProducer %d is created with thread-ID %d", prod2.id, new_thread_id);

  new_thread_id = oslab_create_thread((void *)Producer, &prod3, &(stack3[0x3ff]));
  if( new_thread_id < 0 ) fatal_error( "cannot start Producer 3" );
  printf("\nProducer %d is created with thread-ID %d", prod3.id, new_thread_id);

  new_thread_id = oslab_create_thread((void *)Consumer, &cons1, &(stack4[0x3ff]));
  if( new_thread_id < 0 ) fatal_error( "cannot start Consumer 1" );
  printf("\nConsumer %d is created with thread-ID %d", cons1, new_thread_id);

  new_thread_id = oslab_create_thread((void *)Consumer, &cons2, &(stack5[0x3ff]));
  if( new_thread_id < 0 ) fatal_error( "cannot start Consumer 2" );
  printf("\nConsumer %d is created with thread-ID %d", cons2, new_thread_id);

  oslab_idle(); /* Must be called here! */
}



/*
 * NextPrime
 * 
 * Return the first prime number larger than the integer
 * given as a parameter. The integer must be positive.
 */
#define PRIME_FALSE   0     /* Constant to help readability. */
#define PRIME_TRUE    1     /* Constant to help readability. */
int NextPrime( int inval )
{
   int perhapsprime;        /* Holds a tentative prime while we check it. */
   int testfactor;          /* Holds various factors for which we test perhapsprime. */
   int found;               /* Flag, false until we find a prime. */

   if (inval < 3 )          /* Initial sanity check of parameter. */
   {
     if(inval <= 0) return(1);  /* Return 1 for zero or negative input. */
     if(inval == 1) return(2);  /* Easy special case. */
     if(inval == 2) return(3);  /* Easy special case. */
   }
   else
   {
     /* Testing an even number for primeness is pointless, since
      * all even numbers are divisible by 2. Therefore, we make sure
      * that perhapsprime is larger than the parameter, and odd. */
     perhapsprime = ( inval + 1 ) | 1 ;
   }
   /* While prime not found, loop. */
   for( found = PRIME_FALSE; found != PRIME_TRUE; perhapsprime += 2 )
   {
     /* Check factors from 3 up to perhapsprime/2. */
     for( testfactor = 3; testfactor <= (perhapsprime >> 1) + 1; testfactor += 1 )
     {
       found = PRIME_TRUE;      /* Assume we will find a prime. */
       if( (perhapsprime % testfactor) == 0 ) /* If testfactor divides perhapsprime... */
       {
         found = PRIME_FALSE;   /* ...then, perhapsprime was non-prime. */
         goto check_next_prime; /* Break the inner loop, go test a new perhapsprime. */
       }
     }
     check_next_prime:;         /* This label is used to break the inner loop. */
     if( found == PRIME_TRUE )  /* If the loop ended normally, we found a prime. */
     {
       return( perhapsprime );  /* Return the prime we found. */
     } 
   }
   return( perhapsprime );      /* When the loop ends, perhapsprime is a real prime. */
}
```

When I run the program, the beginning of the FIFO queue is written over and it seems that the first 30 primes are lost when the consumer starts:

```
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5059 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5077 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5081 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8009 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8011 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8017 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8039 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8053 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8059 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5051 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5059 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5077 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5081 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8009 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8011
```

If I use the semaphores I don't get this problem and the consumer gets all the primes. Do you have an idea why I get this problem for this version of my project?

### Update

Now I changed the `Producer` function to call `yield` and then the Producer will yield for each prime number that is produced (so therefore I think that only one prime will be produced for each Producer's timeslice).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "oslab_lowlevel_h.h"

int NextPrime( int );

#define FIFO_SIZE 10

/* Declare a structure to hold a producer's starting value,
 * and an integer for the Producer-number (Producer 1, 2 or 3). */
struct Prod {
    int startvalue;
    int id;
};

unsigned int stack1[0x400]; /* Stack for thread 1 */
unsigned int stack2[0x400]; /* Stack for thread 2 */
unsigned int stack3[0x400]; /* Stack for thread 3 */
unsigned int stack4[0x400]; /* Stack for thread 4 */
unsigned int stack5[0x400]; /* Stack for thread 5 */

/* Declare variables for the First-In-First-Out Queue */
int  Fifo[FIFO_SIZE];        /* Array holding FIFO queue data. */
int  rdaddr;                /* Next unread entry when reading from queue. */
int  wraddr;                /* Next free entry when writing into queue. */

/* Declaration of semaphore variables.
 * 
 * Sorry for the lack of comments, but part of the purpose of the lab
 * is that you should find things out by reading the actual code. */
int  rdmutex = 1;
int  wrmutex = 1;
int  nrempty = FIFO_SIZE;
int  nrfull = 0;

/*
 * fatal_error
 * 
 * Print a message, then stop execution.
 * This function never returns; after printing
 * the message, it enters an infinite loop.
 */
void fatal_error( char * msg)
{
  printf( "\nFatal error: %s\n", msg );
  while( 1 );
}

/*
 * Sleep
 * 
 * Delay execution by keeping the CPU busy for a while,
 * counting down to zero.
 */
void Sleep (int n)
{
    while (n--);
}


void Signal( int *sem )
{

  oslab_begin_critical_region();
  *sem = *sem + 1;
  oslab_end_critical_region();
}


void Wait( int *sem )
{
  /* Disable interrupts. */
  oslab_begin_critical_region();
  while ( *sem <= 0 )
    {
      /* If we should wait, enable interrupts again. */
      oslab_end_critical_region();

      //  oslab_yield(); /* Perhaps we should yield here? */

      /* Disable interrupts again before next iteration in loop. */
      oslab_begin_critical_region();
    }
    /* We have waited long enough - the semaphore-value is now
     * greater than zero. Decrease it. */
    *sem = *sem - 1;
    /* Enable interrupts again. */
    oslab_end_critical_region();
}

/*
 * PutFifo
 * 
 * Insert an integer into the FIFO queue.
 */
void PutFifo( int tal )
{
  //  Wait (&nrempty);      /* Wait for nrempty? */
  //  Wait (&wrmutex);      /* Wait for wrmutex? */

  Fifo[wraddr] = tal;       /* Write to FIFO array. */
    //  printf("\nPutFifo:  %d ", tal); /* Optional debug output */
    //  printf("\nwraddr = %d ", wraddr); /* Optional debug output. */
  wraddr = wraddr + 1;      /* Increase index into FIFO array,
                               to point to the next free position. */
  /* Wrap around the index, if it has reached the end of the array. */
  if (wraddr == FIFO_SIZE ) wraddr = 0;

  //  Signal (&wrmutex);    /* Signal wrmutex? */
  //  Signal (&nrfull);     /* Signal nrfull? */
}

/*
 * GetFifo
 * 
 * Extract the next integer from the FIFO queue.
 */
int GetFifo( void )
{
  int retval;               /* Declare temporary for return value. */

  //  Wait (&nrfull);       /* Wait for nrfull? */
  //  Wait (&rdmutex);      /* Wait for rdmutex? */

  retval = Fifo[rdaddr];    /* Get value from FIFO array. */
    //  printf("\nGetFifo:  %d ", retval); /* Optional debug output */
    //  printf("\nrdaddr = %d ", rdaddr); /* Optional debug output */
  rdaddr = rdaddr + 1;      /* Increase index into FIFO array,
                               to point to the next free position. */
  /* Wrap around the index, if it has reached the end of the array. */
  if (rdaddr == FIFO_SIZE ) rdaddr = 0;

  //  Signal (&rdmutex);    /* Signal rdmutex? */
  //  Signal (&nrempty);    /* Signal nrempty? */

  return (retval);          /* Return value fetched from FIFO. */
}


int NextPrime( int );

void Producer( struct Prod * prodstruct )
{
  int next;                 /* Will hold the prime we just produced. */
  int prodid;               /* Tells whether we are producer 1, 2 or 3. */
  next = prodstruct -> startvalue; /* Get starting value from parameter. */
  prodid = prodstruct -> id;/* Get producer number from parameter. */
  while( 1 )                /* Loop forever. */
  {
    next = NextPrime (next);/* Produce a new prime. */
    printf("\nNext Prime from producer %d is %d",prodid,next); /* Informational output. */
    PutFifo(next);          /* Write prime into FIFO. */
    oslab_yield();        /* Perhaps we should yield here? */
  }
}

void Consumer( int * tal )
{
  int next;                 /* Will hold the prime we are to consume. */
  int consid = *tal;        /* Tells whether we are consumer 1 or 2. */
  while( 1 )                /* Loop forever. */
  {
    next = GetFifo();       /* Get a newly produced prime from the FIFO. */
    printf("\nConsumer %d gets Prime %d ",consid, next); /* Informational output. */
    Sleep(2000);            /* Symbolic work. */
  //  oslab_yield();        /* Perhaps we should yield here? */ 
  }
}

int main( void )
{
  int new_thread_id; /* Thread ID variable. */
  struct Prod prod1, prod2, prod3;  /* Producer starting-values. */
  int cons1, cons2;                 /* Consumer starting-values. */

  rdaddr = 0;               /* FIFO initialization. */
  wraddr = 0;               /* FIFO initialization. */
  printf("\nSystem starting...");

  prod1.startvalue = 2000;
  prod1.id = 1;

  prod2.startvalue = 5000;
  prod2.id = 2;

  prod3.startvalue = 8000;
  prod3.id = 3;

  cons1 = 1;
  cons2 = 2;

  new_thread_id = oslab_create_thread((void *)Producer, &prod1, &(stack1[0x3ff]));
  if( new_thread_id < 0 ) fatal_error( "cannot start Producer 1" );
  printf("\nProducer %d is created with thread-ID %d", prod1.id, new_thread_id);

  new_thread_id = oslab_create_thread((void *)Producer, &prod2, &(stack2[0x3ff]));
  if( new_thread_id < 0 ) fatal_error( "cannot start Producer 2" );
  printf("\nProducer %d is created with thread-ID %d", prod2.id, new_thread_id);

  new_thread_id = oslab_create_thread((void *)Producer, &prod3, &(stack3[0x3ff]));
  if( new_thread_id < 0 ) fatal_error( "cannot start Producer 3" );
  printf("\nProducer %d is created with thread-ID %d", prod3.id, new_thread_id);

  new_thread_id = oslab_create_thread((void *)Consumer, &cons1, &(stack4[0x3ff]));
  if( new_thread_id < 0 ) fatal_error( "cannot start Consumer 1" );
  printf("\nConsumer %d is created with thread-ID %d", cons1, new_thread_id);

  new_thread_id = oslab_create_thread((void *)Consumer, &cons2, &(stack5[0x3ff]));
  if( new_thread_id < 0 ) fatal_error( "cannot start Consumer 2" );
  printf("\nConsumer %d is created with thread-ID %d", cons2, new_thread_id);


  oslab_idle(); /* Must be called here! */
}
```

The change is that I commented in the code `oslab_yield(); /* Perhaps we should yield here? */` so now I suppose that there is only one prime number produced per timeslice(?)

```
System starting...
Producer 1 is created with thread-ID 1
Producer 2 is created with thread-ID 2
Producer 3 is created with thread-ID 3
Consumer 1 is created with thread-ID 4
Consumer 2 is created with thread-ID 5
#### Thread yielded after using 1 tick.
Performing thread-switch number 1. The system has been running for 1 ticks.
Switching from thread-ID 0 to thread-ID 1.

Next Prime from producer 1 is 2003
#### Thread yielded after using 5 ticks.
Performing thread-switch number 2. The system has been running for 6 ticks.
Switching from thread-ID 1 to thread-ID 2.

Next Prime from producer 2 is 5003
#### Thread yielded after using 11 ticks.
Performing thread-switch number 3. The system has been running for 17 ticks.
Switching from thread-ID 2 to thread-ID 3.

Next Prime from producer 3 is 8009
#### Thread yielded after using 16 ticks.
Performing thread-switch number 4. The system has been running for 33 ticks.
Switching from thread-ID 3 to thread-ID 4.

Consumer 1 gets Prime 2003 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5003 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8009 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2003 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5003 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8009 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2003 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5003 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8009 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2003 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5003 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8009 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Performing thread-switch number 5. The system has been running for 133 ticks.
Switching from thread-ID 4 to thread-ID 5.

Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 2003 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 5003 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 8009 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 2003 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 5003 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 8009 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 2003 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 5003 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 8009 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 2003 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 5003 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 8009 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Performing thread-switch number 6. The system has been running for 233 ticks.
Switching from thread-ID 5 to thread-ID 0.

#### Thread yielded after using 0 ticks.
Performing thread-switch number 7. The system has been running for 233 ticks.
Switching from thread-ID 0 to thread-ID 1.

Next Prime from producer 1 is 2011
#### Thread yielded after using 5 ticks.
Performing thread-switch number 8. The system has been running for 238 ticks.
Switching from thread-ID 1 to thread-ID 2.

Next Prime from producer 2 is 5009
#### Thread yielded after using 11 ticks.
Performing thread-switch number 9. The system has been running for 249 ticks.
Switching from thread-ID 2 to thread-ID 3.

Next Prime from producer 3 is 8011
#### Thread yielded after using 16 ticks.
Performing thread-switch number 10. The system has been running for 265 ticks.
Switching from thread-ID 3 to thread-ID 4.

Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2003 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5003 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8009 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2011 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5009 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8011 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2003 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5003 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8009 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2011 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5009 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8011 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2003 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5003 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8009 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2011 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5009 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8011 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2003 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5003 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8009 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 
Performing thread-switch number 11. The system has been running for 365 ticks.
Switching from thread-ID 4 to thread-ID 5.

Consumer 2 gets Prime 5009 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 8011 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 2003 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 5003 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 8009 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 2011 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 5009 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 8011 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 2003 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 5003 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 8009 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 2011 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 5009 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 8011 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 2003 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 5003 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 8009 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 2011 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 5009 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 8011 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 2003 
Consumer 2 gets Prime 5003 
Performing thread-switch number 12. The system has been running for 465 ticks.
Switching from thread-ID 5 to thread-ID 0.

#### Thread yielded after using 0 ticks.
Performing thread-switch number 13. The system has been running for 465 ticks.
Switching from thread-ID 0 to thread-ID 1.

Next Prime from producer 1 is 2017
#### Thread yielded after using 5 ticks.
Performing thread-switch number 14. The system has been running for 470 ticks.
Switching from thread-ID 1 to thread-ID 2.

Next Prime from producer 2 is 5011
#### Thread yielded after using 11 ticks.
Performing thread-switch number 15. The system has been running for 481 ticks.
Switching from thread-ID 2 to thread-ID 3.

Next Prime from producer 3 is 8017
#### Thread yielded after using 16 ticks.
Performing thread-switch number 16. The system has been running for 497 ticks.
Switching from thread-ID 3 to thread-ID 4.
2094 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8009 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2011 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5009 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8011 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2017 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5011 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8017 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2003 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5003 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8009 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2011 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5009 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8011 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2017 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5011 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8017 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2003 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5003 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8009 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2011 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5009 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8011 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2017 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5011 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8017
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nick, you have a couple of issues.

First, the producers can't just write into the fifo.  You need to check that it has room.  (This is that wraddr+1 != rdaddr.  Modulo FIFO_SIZE)  You also need the consumers to check that the fifo isn't empty.  (This is wraddr != rdaddr.  Modulo FIFO_SIZE)

The next problem deals with scheduling.  How is the oslab scheduler implemented?  Is there only one thread of execution?  If so, it is pre-emptive, etc?  In any event, if one thread gets part way through the PutFifo and the next thread starts PutFifo, there is no protection against dual updating.  In fact, wraddr could be corrupted so that you lose entries.  You can do a generalized Dekker algorithm (see wikipedia - at the bottom of the page you will see pointers to Petersen and other algorithms).  Consumer side has similar problem.

I think that your problems are a combination of the two issues above.  So how do you fix it?  I would write a Sync and Unsync routine for each addr (wr and rd).  Under the cover, you could do mutexes, etc for the second thing you want to do.  You could also do a Dekker, etc for the first pass you want to do.  Put the Sync before the PutFifo and Unsync after PutFifo.  Similarly for GetFifo.

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: But it's still completely illogical that the first primes are not consumer. We find no explaination and no solution for this bug. This is an exercise that I'm doing learning C and we should not be expected to get this problems that ruins the entire studies for illogical bugs.

Comment: Look at the output.  Prod1 dumps 23 primes to the FIFO.  The first 10 are overwritten with the second 10.  These a overwritten by the next3 from prod1 and the first 7 from prod2.  5059 is now in the first slot of the FIFO and the consumer reads it.  My answer above said that you need to check that you aren't overwriting the FIFO.  Waddr and rdaddr need to be compared.  To do this correctly, you need a semaphore to keep dual updates from happening.  Read what I wrote carefully and let me know what else you need.  Don't get upset, this isn't a C issue, just a mutlithreading issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I think that it works if I enable the `yield` for the Producer function only. Then the Producer will produce only one prime number and then yield and the consumer will consumer eveything from the beginnning.

Comment: Good to hear, but is the GetFifo protected from dual updates?  If a thread must explicitly yield the CPU before another thread executes, then you are fine.  If not (or there are multiple cores), then the consumer side needs to protect the rdaddr variable from allowing both consumer threads from reading the same prime.  Example, 1st cons executes retval=Fifo[rdaddr], gets interrupted, 2nd cons does same statement.  Both have same value and both could do the next statement and then miss the next one.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your FIFO and semaphore variables should be declared `volatile`.
2. Nothing in your code calls `Wait`

Comment: 3. Read/write of global variables without sync mechanisms (semaphore or mutex).

Comment: Yes, it works if I activate the semaphores. But it's supposed to work also with no semaphores, and it does besides the first 30 primes or so. I'l try to update the Q with more details, it works perfectly with the semaphore but I'm also supposed to get the primes with no sempahores on.